# How to retrieve data from firebase , without changes in the data?

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

//   This is the MainActivity, I have used firebase to store sample data, where I can update and retrieve. 
But retrieval of data is possible only when there is a data change,but I want to see my data which is in firebase already
[here is the data base structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMXgU.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMXgU.jpg)

```
public class MainActivity extends 
 AppCompatActivity {
EditText name,weight;
Button uploadBtn;
TextView itemName,itemWeight;
DatabaseReference databaseReference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Map<String,String>values=new HashMap<>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    name=findViewById(R.id.inputItemName);
    weight=findViewById(R.id.inputItemWeight);
    uploadBtn=findViewById(R.id.uploadButton);
    itemName=findViewById(R.id.resultName);
    itemWeight=findViewById(R.id.resultWeight);
```

// Here as you can see I have used an ValueEventListener to show the retrieve values from database before uploading the new Values But it is not working , unless the values of data are changed (that is it works only after uploading new values).

```
 ValueEventListener valueEventListener=new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String nameD=(String) dataSnapshot.child("Name").getValue();
            String weightD = (String) dataSnapshot.child("Weight").getValue();
            itemName.setText(nameD);
            itemWeight.setText(weightD+" Kg");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };
    databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
    uploadBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            values.put("Name",name.getText().toString());
            values.put("Weight",weight.getText().toString());
            databaseReference.child("UToouch").setValue(values);

        }
    });

    databaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                 String nameDb=(String) dataSnapshot.child("Name").getValue();
                 String weightDb = (String) dataSnapshot.child("Weight").getValue();
                 itemName.setText(nameDb);
                 itemWeight.setText(weightDb+" Kg");
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean through "without changes in the data"?

Comment: without uploading the new values .(overiding the existig data)

Comment: So you basically say that you attach a listener and you don't get any data?

Comment: Yea , I don't get the data unless I change that is update my existing values ,(name, weight ) . Basically i just want to retrieve my existing values in data base and I am not able to do it .

Comment: Please add your database structure as a **JSON** or at least as a **screenshot**.

Comment: I have posted the database screenshot above please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to get values of your `Name` and `Weight` properties, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference ref = rootRef.child("UToouch");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String name = dataSnapshot.child("Name").getValue(String.class);
        String weight = dataSnapshot.child("Weight").getValue(String.class);
        Log.d(TAG, name + " / " + weight);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The output in your logcat will be:

```
rittesh / pv
```